# For Maharudram or Athirudram how many priests should chant the rudram?

Tags: shiva, vedic-chanting, rudram

For *Maharudram* or *Athirudram*, how many priests should chant the *rudram*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maha Rudra Yajna is one of the highest forms of community worship ,with the involvement of 11 Ritwiks reciting the Sri Rudra Prasna 11 times on 11 occassions ,totalling 1,331 times followed by one tenth (133) recitations for the purpose of the homam.